# What are the advantages and disadvantages of having landing gear doors?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, landing-gear, boeing-737, airbus-a320

To make comparison easy, let us take the example of B737 and A320, both similar aircrafts with retractable landing gear.

As seen on the photo below, the B737 doesn't have gear doors for the wheels,

[image: 737 Underside View]

but the A320 does

[image: A320 Planform View]

Obviously, Boeing and Airbus made different choices for the same feature and both seem reasonable. Both aircraft models are well accepted by the airlines.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both designs?

EDIT: I put links to other images where both aircraft are retracting landing gear after take off. The difference is obvious as we can see the landing gear doors operated for the [A320](http://www.airliners.net/photo/CSA---Czech/Airbus-A320-214/1342671/&sid=0dcd645676e4024c412c6f49c108d858) and no doors for the [B737](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Transavia-Airlines/Boeing-737-8K2/1340730/&sid=6144b6515e119662f895aaf02e1e7f5a)'s wheel.

Comment: [here is a better image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:737under.jpg) of the lack of gear doors

Comment: @ratchetfreak  I prefer the [images](http://www.airliners.net/photo/CSA---Czech/Airbus-A320-214/1342671/&sid=0dcd645676e4024c412c6f49c108d858) I originally linked (before the question was edited) because they show both aircrafts while the gears is moving and there is no ambiguity on whether the [B737](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Transavia-Airlines/Boeing-737-8K2/1340730/&sid=6144b6515e119662f895aaf02e1e7f5a) has wheel doors or of it is a painting on the aircrafts body.

Comment: I've read in an Air & Cosmos magazine (french) that Boeing decided to go without gear doors (737-100/200) because of the design : ground clearance and belly volume. But I'm sorry, I've dumped the magazine long ago :/ Wether the Air & Cosmos article were correct or not, I don't know, sometimes they aren't. That's why this is a comment but NOT an answer at all.

Comment: The 737 _does_ have gear doors.  It's just that those doors happen to be the wheels themselves.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Benefits of gear doors**

- With gear doors, there are fewer constraints on the retracted gear position. This is especially important in larger aircraft with larger and more complex landing gear. It doesn't need to be flush with fuselage or streamlined (737 also uses [hubcaps](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4008/4331431885_1bb49a8edd.jpg)).
- The gear doors provide a good aerodynamic surface
- Opening to gear bay can be larger and easier to access

**Drawbacks of gear doors**

- Extra weight for the door and the mechanisms
- Extra complexity of opening another door (possibility for [things to go wrong](http://avherald.com/h?article=469338e0))

Comment: "gear can be in the best position when retracted"  what is "the best position"

Comment: @rbp I tried to word that one better

Comment: How is fewer constraints necessarily a good thing, and why is it important in larger aircraft?

Comment: @rbp everything in an aircraft is limited by space and many other factors. The fewer constraints on a system, the easier it is to address other requirements. And as gear gets larger, it will have more components and take up more space, making the problem more complicated.

Comment: By saying "everything," you lose specificity, which makes that part of the answer nearly meaningless. You could have just as made it a drawback: "because space is required for gear doors under the fuselage, there is less space for cargo, etc."

Comment: @rbp With gear doors, the gear position is not constrained to one place. More options can yield better compromises.

Comment: I think part of the rationale behind the 737 approach was that the retracted gear is more compact - shallower wells, can be closer together without the space consumed by doors, hinges, and actuators

Comment: @fooot What about cooling brakes? Would lack of doors have any advantage?

Answer (score 4):

Doors add weight and complexity to the aircraft, and need to be inspected and maintained. But doors also provide a smooth surface for the air to travel over, so they would have less drag. The 737 does have doors, but for the gear struts, but the wheels lay fairly flat against the fuselage, so drag is minimized.

Comment: Also note the exhaust from the packs looks like they come our right ahead of the tires, so they are at least putting drag sources in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in Boeing's case. it was decided to eliminate doors because they add COST.  When they were designing the 737, it was a relatively small, budget aircraft being built for regional service.

Comment: Could you expand a little? Somehow I find it difficult to believe that cost would be a major driving factor in this case.

Comment: You may enhance your answer by explaining why it differs between the A320 and the B737