# Why does the Aurora D8 have vents on the bottom of its fuselage?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, experimental-aircraft

The [Aurora D8](https://www.aurora.aero/d8/) is a concept of an experimental aircraft (not an actual aircraft for now), described in this site. It's discussed in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15375/how-is-the-d8-double-bubble-aircraft-by-nasa-so-efficient) here on Aviation.SX.

I was watching the embedded video on the website I linked to, and it seems to show a couple of (intake?) vents on the bottom of the fuselage. You can even see this in the freeze-frame before playing the video.

What could these be used for? Do they suck in air for use in the engine? In the cabin? Elsewhere?

Comment: Are your referring to the two round, donut-shaped dark areas on the bottom of the fuselage between the wings? If so, rather than vents, those would presumably be the landing gear in the retracted position. See the [wheel well of the B737](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16476/12720) for a similar configuration.

Comment: @JWalters: Indeed, I accepted that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about the dark spots here...

[image: (screenshot from aurora.aero, annotated by me)]

...then those are the tires of the main landing gear. This is the same approach [used by the Boeing 737](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9094/39) — as discussed in another question here.

By skipping main landing gear bay doors, the aircraft's total weight is reduced. An aerodynamicist could provide a more confident answer, but the impact of the exposed wheels to the airflow would be relatively minor and not impact drag meaningfully.